# Really Struggling with Class Library, How do I Handle Lazy Loading/ConnectionString in Library?

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, lazy-loading, class-library

I'm really struggling to get my head around the idea of working with a Class Library and I'm pretty much at the point of just maintaining separate projects with duplicate classes rather than a shared class library.

I've created a solution that contains a single class library project and two web applications. My main problems are the connection strings. These are held/declared in the web projects and I'm having to pass them into the class library every time I perform any kind of data access. I sort of understand why I should do this so I'm going with it for the moment.

This has now led me to a problem/question with lazy loading. I'm using lazy loading for the following property:

```
    Public Property KeyRelationshipManager() As Employee
        Get
            If _keyRelationshipManager Is Nothing Then
                _keyRelationshipManager = Employee.GetEmployee(_keyRelationshipManagerStaffNumber)
                Return _keyRelationshipManager
            Else
                Return _keyRelationshipManager
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As AECOM.Employee)
            _keyRelationshipManager = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Because this property is using the function:

```
Employee.GetEmployee
```

I need to pass in the connection string to that function.

This means I would need to pass the connection string in to the property every time I use it so I could pass it into the function.

Is this correct? It doesn't 'feel' right to me because I'm going to have to adjust a huge number of functions and property and pass through the connections string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing the connection string in to the class library? Use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myClassLibraryConnection"]` in your class library. As long as you have that connection string in both your host applications' config files, it should be fine. It's the web.config files' jobs to bind the configuration of different class libraries to form a single application.

Comment: Because I thought that was the right way to do it, seems wrong to me but that's what I've read. Also I can't access ConfigurationManager in my library. Is there a reference I need to add or namespace to import? I would much prefer to do it that way.

Comment: Well passing it in would certainly be better than hardcoding it in the class library. However, specifying your connection string in the host application's web.config is effectively the same as passing it in - your host app is telling your class library which database to use.

`ConfigurationManager` is in `System.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: thanks for that. I've been really down with this but I think I'm finally getting there.

Comment: I would mark your answer as useful but I don't have the rep yet so here you go: +1!

Comment: Also should add, you need to reference System.Configuration.dll